# Paypal with multiple recurrent subscriptions only accepts the first one

Tags: paypal, recurring

Im trying to make a **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile** on Paypal with two subscription items, but only works for the first one, the second one fails with "Failure" and returns an 11581 error ("Profile description is invalid").

What I do first is a **SetExpressCheckout** call with something like:

```
...
L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments
L_BILLINGTYPE1=RecurringPayments
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=First subscription
L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION1=Second subscription
...
```

I get a Success response, then I call **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile** for each subscription item with all the required POST fields with their correct **DESC** field that matches the L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0 and L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION1 in the SetExpressCheckout call.

The first subscription gets a Success response, but not the second one with the error mentioned above.

The DESC fields are short alphanumeric strings (Paypal wants a 127 string length limit).

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?